# Set Mac application window bounds from Terminal?

Tags: terminal, applescript

Can the bounds of a Mac application window be set directly from Terminal?

I use this Applescript (called by keystroke handler Spark) all day long, varied per application –

```
 set bounds of window 1 to {50, 50, 1200, 700}
```

Forklift 3.3.1 does not handle Applescript, and I have not found a way to do this using **tell application "System Events"** etc.

Internet search turns up nothing useful, but is there not a simple Terminal command like Applescript's **set bounds** that can do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave.

```
set frontMostApp to (path to frontmost application)
tell application "Finder" to set appName to name of (get properties of frontMostApp)
set bounds of window 1 of application appName to {50, 50, 1200, 700}
```

Here is a different version using only System Events

```
tell application "System Events" to tell window 1 of (process 1 where it is frontmost)
    try
        set position to {50, 50}
        set size to {1200, 700}
    end try
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you. This works in applications that handle Applescript (have their own Applescript dictionaries). It does not work in Forklift 3.3.1 because it does not handle Applescript at all. Getting the name of the application with Applescript (as above) would not help. For Forklift it would need to be done with Terminal code, if that is possible.

Comment: wch1zpink 

Yes this (above) works: the “different version using only System Events”. 

The key seems to be not using the application name, only referring to process 1. (Though why it works I can’t guess, as the application does not read or handle Applescript.)

Comment: The first two line of code can be replaced with this one line: `tell application "Finder" to set appName to displayed name of (path to frontmost application)`

Comment: ① As an alternative to retrieving the frontmost application name without involving _Finder_: `set appName to the name of the application named (path to frontmost application)`.  But, since you end up using the `application` object specifier, you can make this a bit briefer: `set A to the application named (path to frontmost application)`.  As a rule-of-thumb with AppleScript, which gets truer as time passes, if you can avoid getting _Finder_ to do something, it's a good idea to. ② Why the `try` block ?

Comment: The try block is in the event that the front most application has no open windows As to avoiding it throwing an error

Comment: THIS WORKS – wch1zpink’s code above (“a different version using only System Events”). I don’t have enough points to vote. Set position & set size work. Set window bounds does not work. Try block is needed to avoid error if no window exists.